# How to get value from subquery in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have this two tables:

```
Article:
- id:(int) primary key, autoincrement, not null,
- title:(varchar) not null,
- price:(decimal) not null,
- cart_id(int) not null, //foreign key 
- book_id(int) not null, //foreign key 
- image_id(int) not null, //foreign key 


Image:
- id:(int) primary key, autoincrement, not null,
- image:(Blob) not null
```

and

```
 Book:
- id:(int) primary key, autoincrement, not null,
- title:(varchar) not null,
- price:(decimal) not null,
- image_id(int) not null, //foreign key
```

I want when inserting into Article to insert also right `image_id`, here is query where i try to that:

```
insert into article(title,price,cart_id,book_id) 
values('Book1',20.00,387,
(select b.id from books b join article a where b.title =  a.title limit 1))
```

When i run query like this(without image) it works fine, but i can't figure out query with `image_id`. So i thought maybe if i can get value from subquery `select b.id from books b join article a where b.title =  a.title` i can just to this`select id from image where id=` result from that query(i have foreign key book_image in book table btw). Am i totally missing point if not, how to solve this?

Comment: have you tested your query, i don't think that book_id can be right. you join two tables and get one row, without any order. Further myn data are double in your database, that is nort goodm the tables need urgent normalization. last the image id has also come fro somewhehre idealy fromthe gui

Comment: Can you include the schema for the books table please?

Comment: @armitage it's same as `article` only without book_id and cart_id as fk

Comment: @nbk it is good. In my code in jdbc looks like this `select b.id from books b join article a where b.title ='"+title+"'limit 1` that title is argument in method.

Comment: i also guessed so but your code abouve doesn't show it it show have instead of b.title =  a.title b.title =  'Book1'  still this is redundant, you don#t need title in bitth tables

Comment: @nbk okay, but what about image problem?

Comment: When you get the imageid also from book table make a second select and get the id, else, how should i know how you should get you data, if you don't post all tables

Comment: @nbk i edited to include book table. Article is inserted when user clicks`add to cart` button,so basically articles are inserted in cart, i'm explaining just in case if you are confused.

Comment: Both title and image_id are redundant in the article table.  When you need them, get them from the books table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But as i said you don't need in article

title and image, as they are already existent in books and you can always join the books table

But you would do this so

```
INSERT INTO article(title,price,cart_id,book_id,image_id) 
VALUES ('Book1',20.00,387,
(select b.id from books b  where b.title =  'Book1' limit 1),
(select b.image_id from books b where b.title =  'Book1' limit 1))
```

Comment: you're trying to insert 5 values into 4 columns

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Why two selects if one is enough?

```
INSERT INTO article(title,price,cart_id,book_id,image_id) 
  select b.title, 20.00, 387, b.id, b.image_id
    from books b  where b.title =  'Book1' limit 1
```

But since image and title can be retrieved from the books table, you really shouldn't store them in the article table also.

Comment: You should put your comment in the answer as well. It is probably better to do the right thing than to do the wrong thing the right way